# How to make a Windows computer logoff when press power button?

Tags: windows

It only have shutdown or sleep options, can I make it log off?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, at least natively. As a workaround, you can easily assign a keyboard shortcut like Ctrl-L to logoff quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my investigation, it cannot be done.

1. Windows itself does not have a setting for that.
2. It is impossible to effectively write an app that responds to the pressure of the power button with a logoff action. When set to "Do nothing", Windows does not send any messages to the effect that the button is pressed. When set to other actions... well, you don't want other actions to happen now, do you?

Answer (score 0):

You can find power button GUID [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt608287) (which can then be manually adjusted with powercfg), but long story short it only supports predefined power states actions.

It [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392653/hook-system-power-button-in-windows) be possible to make a 3rd party program that hooks into it and separately trigger whatever other behavior you want though.